# How to replace Complex Multiline Text in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, sed, macos

I want to replace a specific multiline text from a file in bash, but getting an error.

I think it's failing because of it's multiline, when I test the code with single line (with spaces and special characters) it works fine, but when I add the full multiline target and replacement, it fails.

**file.txt**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            O-HELLO-1
        </title>
    </head>
</html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            O-HELLO-2
        </title>
    </head>
</html>
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

target="<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            O-HELLO-1
        </title>
   </head>
</html>";

replacement="<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            R-HELLO-1
        </c>
    </b>
</a>";

echo "------------------";
out=$(sed -i -e "s/$target/$replacement/g" file.txt);

if [[ -n $out ]]; then
    cat file.txt;
    if [ -f file.txt-e ]; then
        rm file.txt-e;
        echo "------------------";
        echo "duplicate file removed.";
    fi
    echo;
fi
echo "------------------";
```

**error.log**

```
sed: 1: "s/<html>
    <head>
    ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Comment: You'd probably do better loading that markup file into a JavaScript context that supports classes such as [XMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument), because the grammar of markup languages is at a higher hierarchy than those can be processed with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

First, a word of guidance. This "text" appears to actually be a markup language like XML or similar. Processing such complex and nuanced input as simple, unformed text are very likely to cause problems in the long term. I strongly suggest using a tool like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or similar instead.

All that said, one solution would be to use variables, as provided by (for example) GNU awk:

```
awk -v target="$target" -v replacement="$replacement" '{ gsub(target, replacement, $0) } 1'
```

I again repeat: if you intend to do this repeatedly, or without supervision of the results, please save yourself the headache and use a program which actually deals with the ins and outs of the markup language you are using, eg. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), Python's `lxml`, or similar.

Comment: No, this `#` fix is not working `unterminated substitute pattern`.

Comment: @T.I.N.R.F.M. If you cannot choose a separator character which reliably does not appear, then as suggested in the answer, you should use something like XMLStarlet or lxml.

Comment: `awk: newline in string <html2>
ll... at source line 1
awk: newline in string <a>
m... at source line 1`

Comment: @T.I.N.R.F.M. The awk solution requires GNU awk, but you are (presumably) using BSD awk. Either install it, or (as suggested, again) use lxml or XMLStarlet instead, which are much better suited to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fundamental point of how `sed` operates. It is a line oriented editor as it fetches the input a line ata time. Whereas you are asking it to process a multiline regex, which will obviously never match.

If you have `GNU sed` you can `slurp` the file in by neans of the `-z` option to sed. It looks at the `NUL=\0` record separator, which won't be found in text files. Hence it will read in the whole file as one long record.

We need to tweak the target and replacement vars as they presumably can  contain chars which are treated as regex by sed. So we need to escape them and only then use them in a sed expression.

```
srch=$(printf '%s\n' "$target" |
sed -e '
  H;1h;$!d;x
  s:[][\/^$*.]:\\&:g
  s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/[[:space:]]\\{1,\\}/g
')

repl=$(printf '%s\n' "$replacement" |
sed -e '
  s:[\&/]:\\&:g
  $!s:$:\\:
')

sed -e '$!{' -e 'N;H;s/.*//;x;D' -e '}' -e "s/$srch/$repl/g" file.txt
```

---

**Results:**

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            R-HELLO-1
        </c>
    </b>
</a>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            O-HELLO-2
        </title>
    </head>
</html>
```

---

in case `perl` is installed on your system, then you could use this also; we are matching the same skeleton but varying amounts of whitespace, coz u don't wanna a single space to mess up a match.

```
srch="$target"      \
repl="$replacement" \
perl -0777 -pe '
  (my $re = quotemeta $ENV{srch}) =~ s/(\\\s)+/\\s+/g;
  s/$re/$ENV{repl}/g;
' file.txt
```

Comment: Got an error: `sed: illegal option -- z`. MacOS BigSur 11.2.1

Comment: I have done without the -z option.